# Should this ASP.NET MVC ActionMethod have two views?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm playing around with using ASP.NET MVC3 and have a *very* simple site that only allows you to log in/create an account OR list your account details.

I was wanting to make the homepage .. bascially that. If u're not logged in, then ask them to log in or create a new account. Otherwise, show them their account details. Simple.

So I wasn't sure if I should do something like this ....

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? View("Show") : View("Index");
}
```

That's a pretty contrived example, but it basically describes my question.

I feel that this is not a good way.. but instead I should be redirecting to a different method .. like the real Show ? .. eg. /Show/UserFoo ????

I'm just not sure of what people are doing - a common pattern, here.

Thoughts?

Comment: No, that's not very RESTful. The `/index` resource shouldn't have anything to do with logging in. It also makes cachability harder. Just redirect to `/login` instead, like @Darin suggests. :) So I guess the "common pattern" here is keeping URLs relevant, which is an important part of REST - and the specific pattern for ASP.NET MVC is the aspect-oriented Authorize attribute on the action method.

Comment: As regards using (or not using) a different view, that depends on how much change there is between the authenticated versus the non-authenticated presentation. If a lot of things change between the two, then two different views is fine. If large portions are common then if the view is implemented using controls (that descend from a common base class) such that you can decide at runtime which controls should be used (polymorphism).

Comment: @bzlm, you're assuming that if the user is not authenticated, they need to. There are many cases where the page shown is virtually the same (for authenticated and non-authenticated users). For (a simple) example, on SO if you've logged in you see your user name at the top but if you're not you don't, the rest of the page for the most part is the same.

Comment: @Shiv I'm assuming nothing. The question specifically says "If u're not logged in, then ask them to log in or create a new account. Otherwise, show them their account details". ;)

Comment: @bzlm, ypu, you're correct. I missed that somehow.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute which check if the user is authenticated and if not redirect to the login page.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

You could also write a custom authorization attribute if you don't like the default behavior.

Comment: but what happens if the default page IS index / home page?

Comment: @Pure.Krome, if the default page is /home/index and you decorate the Index action with the `[Authorize]` attribute and the user is not authenticated he will be redirected to the login page. So put this attribute only on controller actions that require authentication.

Comment: Yep .. but i was curious to know if the login page IS the home page. that would mean an infinite redirect, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, no.  Mainly because this will help keep you DRY in case you want to have common content between the two.

Instead do checks inside the view for whether or not someone is authenticated.

Razor (Dry code):

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
Welcome back, @User.Identity.Username!
} else {
Please <a href="/login">login</a>!
}
```

I think this will help keep things DRY.

Comment: So this is still one view, but parts of the view are hidden/not hidden based on some data (eg. user logged in or not).

Answer (score -2):

Make use of the LoginView item:

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server">
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        // this is seen by users who are authenticated, so display info
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        // this is seen by users not authenticated - so display login form
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

You will need something to manage authentication, the `[Authorize]` attribute can do that for you or you can write your own custom implementation.

Comment: Cheers @AndyC but i want to avoid ASP.NET controls like the plague.